# Pandas convert array column into multiple columns with a condition

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas data frame with 2 columns:

- embedding as an array column and size of embedding = *size_of_embedding*
- language

like this:

```
embedding              language
[0.1 0.2 0.3]           fr
[0.1 0.4 0.4]           en
[0.8 0.1 0.1]           fr
```

Given a beginning integer *n = 10*, for each value of embedding column, I want to add a column to the above data frame like this:

```
embedding            language          feature1     feature2  feature3
[0.1 0.2 0.3]          fr              10:0.1        11:0.2    12:0.3
[0.1 0.4 0.4]          en              13:0.1        14:0.4    15:0.4
[0.8 0.1 0.1]          fr              10:0.8        11:0.1    12:0.1
```

So, feature1 = 1st embedding value, feature2 = 2nd embedding value .... For the next language the beginning feature value = *n+size_of_embedding:*.
So, for each language, the number of columns added is exactly equal to the size_of_embedding array. and for each next language encountered, we start with *n+size_of_embedding:*. Is there an easy way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: num of features would be constant for the dataframe? Can a row have `x` features and another have `y` where `x` != `y`?

Comment: num of columns would be constant for a row. In the example, each row will always have 5 columns.

Comment: so it means, every embedding will have 3 features only..

Comment: yes, embedding size is fixed.

Comment: Just the numbers before the `:` will change depending on the language

Comment: In the data frame, I am working with embedding size = 20, and #languages is more than 30. In the question, I had to reduce the scale of the problem in order to explain properly.

Comment: For the sake of my curiosity, what's the use case that you were trying to solve with this? This is an interesting dataset!

Comment: I was attempting to build a tweet recommendation model, tweets being in multiple languages. This was part of RecSys challenge 2020: https://recsys-twitter.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first ensure that the `embedding` column is in fact an array. If it is stored as string, you can convert it to a numpy array like so:

```
df.embedding = df.embedding.apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(x[1:-1], sep=' '))
```

create a lookup list of languages and their starting values, and use that to generate the 
features

```
lookup = {'fr': 10, 'en': 13}
```

If you have too many languages to create this by hand, you could try the following statement, replacing `10` & `3` as is appropriate for your actual dataset

```
lookup = {l:10+i*3 for i, l in enumerate(df.language.drop_duplicates().to_list())}
```

Generating the features is then just a lookup & a list comprehension. Here I've used the helper function `f` to keep the code tidy.

```
def f(lang, embeddings): 
    return [f'{lookup[lang]+i}:{e}' for i, e in enumerate(embedding)]

new_names = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3']
df[new_names] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x.language, x.embedding), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

df now looks like:

```
         embedding language feature1 feature2 feature3
0  [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]       fr   10:0.1   11:0.2   12:0.3
1  [0.1, 0.4, 0.4]       en   13:0.1   14:0.4   15:0.4
2  [0.8, 0.1, 0.1]       fr   10:0.8   11:0.1   12:0.1
```

Comment: I check on my dataset and get back to you.

Comment: The solution works on my data and is generalizable. Any suggestion to make it a little faster is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: @SumitSidana the usages of `apply` can be quickened by using this module - [swifter](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter). This uses parallel processing to apply functions on dataframe rows. you need to install it and then replace `df.apply` by `df.swifter.apply()`, you should see good improvement

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot.

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan, it works for me. Is it possible to specify number of threads? I have 16 cores on my machine. I can see only one being utilized as a result of `htop`. Since, the function, which has been written above is fully parallelizable and the result of one row does not really depend on the other row, it would be nice to use all the cores. Is it possible to specify number of cores? Or, swifter figures out by itself. I couldn't find it by quick Googling

Comment: If your data is that big, perhaps use dask for data processing. It exposes a similar API to pandas and efficiently parallelizes to multiple cores and even a cluster of machines

Answer (score 1):

Longhand

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'embedding':['[0.1 0.2 0.3]','[0.1 0.4 0.4]','[0.8 0.1 0.1]'],'language':['fre','en','fr']})
df['feature1']=0
df['feature2']=0
df['feature3']=0

df['z']=df.embedding.str.strip('\[\]')#Remove the box brackets

    df['y']=df.z.str.findall('(\d+[.]+\d+)')#extract each digit dot digit in the list

    lst=['10:','11:','12:']#Create List lookup for `fr/fre`
    lst2=['13:','14:','15:']##Create List lookup for `en`
```

Create two frames fo fr and en using boolean select

```
 m=df.language.isin(['en'])
    df2=df[~m]
    df3=df[m]
```

Compute `feature1, feature2` and `feature3`

```
df2['k']=[lst+i for i in df2['y']]
df3['m']=[lst2+i for i in df3['y']]
df2['feature1']=[i[0]+i[len(df2['k'])] for i in df2['k']]
df2['feature2']=[i[1]+i[len(df2['k'])+1] for i in df2['k']]
df2['feature3']=[i[2]+i[len(df2['k'])+2] for i in df2['k']]

df3['feature1']=[i[0]+i[len(df3['m'])] for i in df3['m']]
df3['feature2']=[i[1]+i[len(df3['m'])+1] for i in df3['m']]
df3['feature3']=[i[2]+i[len(df3['m'])+2] for i in df3['m']]
```

Concat `df2` and `df3`

```
pd.concat([df3.iloc[:,:5:],df2.iloc[:,:5:]])
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that for language `en` the prefixes before `:` are 13, 14 and 15.